# Missing SSRS Reports After TFS 2017 Install

Tags: tfs

I have a clean install of TFS 2017 Update 1 and SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition SP1. During the install I configured the Reporting option and I can see in the TFS Administration Console that reporting is correctly configured and is running properly. I can also navigate to the SSRS Reports page and I see folders created there for my Test Collection. However, I do not see any folders there for my test team projects and I do not see the Reports link on the web interface or in Visual Studio Team Explorer. It appears that TFS is not creating the default SSRS reports when I create a new Team Project. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: How did you create the projects? From the WebUI or from Visual Studio? Only the creation from Visual Studio will provision the reports.

Comment: @RahulMakwana Which installer, TFS 2017 Update 1 or SQL Server 2017 SP1? I tried both and didn't see that option. I know I can install SSDT using the stand-alone installer but if that was a requirement, I would expect to see it in the MS install documentation and I don't.

Comment: @jessehouwing I created them through the WebUI. I will try to create one from Visual Studio and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @jessehouwing That worked! If you make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a project through the web Ui, no reports and no Sharepoint portal is created.

To create a Sharepoint site and/or to provision reports for your project, you'll need to use visual studio/team explorer to create the team project.

To provision reporting afterwards you can use the tfs 2015 power tools, tfpt.exe I'd guess. At least that works when provisioning reports on tfs 2015, if I remember correctly there has not yet been a 2017 release of this power tool.

Comment: Do you know if the reports are created if the project is created through the API?

Comment: When using the rest api, no. When using the local api which launches a visual studio instance in the background, then yes those can create reporting.

Answer (score 3):

There are not going to be any TFS Power Tools for VS2017.

To add reports after the fact in 2017 use:

TFSConfig addprojectreports /collection:"http://myServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection" /teamproject:MyProject /template:"TemplateName"
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/admin/upload-reports

TFSConfig addprojectreports is available from TFS 2017 Update 1RC2. If you are on TFS 2017 RTM or TFS 2017 Update 1 RC1 then use following method to upload reports.

Install TFS 2017 Update 1 (or TFS 2017 Update 1 RC2) on a separate server, no need to configure it, just the binaries are needed. Then run TFSConfig addprojectreports from your new server (pointed to the Actual server) and upload the reports.